# How to replicate next js "public" folder behaviour with webpack?

Tags: javascript, webpack, next.js

Next js recently added [public folder functionality](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-1#public-directory-support) which in its essence resolves urls like these:

```
background-image: url(/images/test.png);
<img src="/images/test.png" />;
require("/images/test.png")
```

From wherever you are in your source code to a `public` directory located at the root of your project.

I am trying to replicate this in a non next js project that uses webpack, I initially played with `publicPath` property, but I'm either missing something or this is not how its done. Hence the question: Given project structure like this how could I resolve those examples mentioned above to my `public` folder no matter where I am in the project in `prod / dev`?

example project structure

```
public/
  images/
    test.png
src/
  components/
  pages/
webpack.config.js
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've got a little bit tricky solution for this.
Add this configuration to your webpack:

```
   resolve: {
        alias: {
            '/images': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/images')
        }
    },
```

This is tricky solution because webpack will not recognize only '/' alias and you need to set as many aliases as many folders in public folder you have.
Example:

```
   resolve: {
        alias: {
            '/images': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/images'),
            '/audio': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/audio'),
            '/video': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/video'),
            '/etc': path.resolve(__dirname, 'public/etc'),
        }
    },
```

Note: you want to require it, so public folder is not a public (or static, assets it can be called when using ssr) folder now. It will be included to the bundle.