# Next.js serve compiled service.worker.ts file as a static file. No custom server allowed

Tags: webpack, next.js, webpack-dev-server

[Not a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59016131/how-to-replicate-next-js-public-folder-behaviour-with-webpack). Quote: "I am trying to replicate this in a non next js project that uses webpack"

---

In my case(see code below) I am using IN next.js. I want to serve the compiled `service.worker.js` file as if it was inside the public folder. But in my case, the `service.worker.ts` file is outside the `public/` folder. And it is being compiled with webpack first.

Where should I place the result of the compiled `service.worker.ts` file? The goal is to be able to access it at `mydomain.com/service.worker.js`. Maybe I am using the wrong config? Maybe it should be done using `webpackDevMiddleware`?

```
const nectConfig = {
  distDir: 'dist',
  webpack: (config, { buildId, dev, isServer, defaultLoaders, webpack }) => {
    const newConfig = {
      ...config,
      entry: function() {
        return config.entry().then(entry => {
          return {
            ...entry,
            /* where should the output be, so that the service-worker.js file
             can be accessed like any other file under the public/ directory?*/
            './public/service-worker.js': './service-worker.ts'
          };
        });
      },
      output: { ...config.output, globalObject: 'self' }
    };
    return newConfig;
  }
};
```