# Set Next.js to compile .ts files located inside the public/ directory

Tags: typescript, webpack, next.js

[Not a duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61363719/next-js-serve-compiled-service-worker-ts-file-as-a-static-file-no-custom-server)
The title says it all. Imagine we want to have `someFile.ts` located in `public/someFile.ts`. Can we set next.js to serve the compiled version of that file? So when we access `mydomain.com/someFile.js`, we get the same file but transpiled to javascript? I'd also expect the .env variables(defined in next.config.js) to work as well.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @PullJosh I think I did but I can't remember exactly how :(